# Is there a way to open a dynamic link in a browser?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an ionic app where i can send invitations (share app link), I used firebase dynamic links. When I share it, the person who receive the message can open the link in a device (tested for android) and he is redirected to the play store ( app not found because i am still testing it), but if the link is opened on a pc, then browser opens with page not found.

I am new to all the stuff.

Comment: What is the thing you want to achieve exactly? One link to open playstore if opened from android and redirect to website if opened from pc and to app store if device was ios or i miss understood you?

Comment: yes, as you said @MostafaHarb

Answer (score 0):

As the first point, the link that should be shared is your website domain name example.com/anypagename that couldn't be direct accessed.
Whwn user click this link from any place it will redirect him to this website page, And in this page for website you will add a function to detect device, and if device is android, it send a response of google play link and same for ios and if desktop will redirect to main website page.
http://mobiledetect.net
Use this library to achieve what i said above...

Comment: architecture is serverless, firebase as a backend

Comment: Hmmm , but when i asked above in comment you said there is website so depending on that i gave the answer ....

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of success for scenario similar to you by using Branch.io service. It is mostly free with advanced features being priced.

Do have a look at their offering. If not i can help out too.